# with bash putting text line to array

Tags: bash

I've a txt file like this:

```
cat fruits.txt

apple
banana
mango
```

I need put them to bash array:

```
fruit[0]='apple'
fruit[1]='banana'
ftuit[2]='mango'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
fruit=( $(<fruits.txt) )

set | grep fruit
fruit=([0]="apple" [1]="banana" [2]="mango")
```

Comment: Thanks! I need re-read bash documentation :-)

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works out.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` 4 and later:

```
mapfile fruit < fruits.txt
```

To ignore the trailing newline from each line

```
mapfile -t fruit < fruits.txt
```

The command `readarray` is a synonym for `mapfile`.